# Disable URLSession auto retry mechanism in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

When i make post API call using URLSession and a network disconnection happens while the API is in progress, i receive a network error callback from URLSession -

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x2822cc9f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}
```

Then if the network is immediately reconnected, the URLSession silently retries the API call and i don't receive any acknowledgement of the API call made.

As we received network error, we believe that the call has failed and attempt to retry the API. At this point 2 API calls were made, **one from my retry mechanism and another from URL session auto retry mechanism.**

Is there any way i can tell URL session not to auto retry? It is important for me to avoid making duplicate API calls to the backend.

This is my URLSession configuration -

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.waitsForConnectivity = true
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 1
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request.urlRequest!) {data, response, error in
    // Do something
}.resume()
```

Comment: Perhaps using a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate) could work?

Comment: That's a bit surprising. Are you certain that URLSession is retrying the API call, rather than some other part of the network doing it? (How did you confirm this?) Once you receive an error, there shouldn't be additional retries by URLSession. "It is important for me to avoid making duplicate API calls to the backend." It is impossible to guarantee that. It is a normal part of networking infrastructure to automatically retry certain kinds of failures, and disconnection errors can be illusions. See [the Byzantine generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault) for background.

Comment: You can ensure "deliver at most once" by never retrying at the app layer. And you can ensure "deliver at least once" by sending until you receive a confirmation reply from the server. It is impossible to ensure "deliver precisely once." If you need to protect against repeating operations, search for "idempotent api," which is how you build APIs to be resilient to that. This can only be solved through changes to the server; it cannot be done entirely by a client.

Comment: @RobNapier
Thank you for your response. Even i'm a bit surprised with the URLSession behaviour.
The answer to your question "How did i confirm this?" -
The API call i make basically adds a new entry to our database table. In this scenario a duplicate entry was made. 
At the app layer no duplicate calls were made so the only explanation for the duplicate entry was URLSession auto retrying on network reconnection.

Comment: That is not the only explanation. The most likely cause, given that error message, is that your app connects to the server, makes the request, and the server's process crashes before returning a result. To verify that it's coming from URLSession, you would want to look at a network trace in Instruments as a starting point (but this is very unlikely). Another option, more likely than URLSession, would be an intermediate connection (such as a proxy) forwarding the request, but then disconnecting from your app.

Comment: @RobNapier I will look into the other 2 possibilities. Thank you.
Even if the cause were any of these, is there anything i can do at the app layer to avoid this from happening?

Comment: Similar to Rob, I also don't think URLSession retries itself out the box. You can just try a sample app, and replicate the lost internet connection and test the behavior of URLSession. I guess to be able to this out you'd need to slow down your internet a bit, and disconnect while the request is in process or have a request that its response is big. Though a large response may not be an identical simulation for what you're experiencing...

Comment: "is there anything i can do at the app layer to avoid this from happening?" See my previous comment. You cannot achieve "guaranteed one-time delivery" purely at the app layer. This is not an iOS issue. This is a mathematical fact of distributed systems. If you must never have a repeated message, then you must not retry in the app, and you may lose messages. If you must never lose a message, then you need to retry until successful, and you may get duplicates. "Pick one." Working with the server, you can build protocols that are resilient to duplicates, but not purely in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm that two connections are actually made from the one data task you would need to examine your server logs; you would actually see three connections:

- The original connection
- The "retried" connection
- The second connection your code makes after getting the error.

However, I highly doubt that this is what is occurring. You will see two connections; your original connection and the second connection your code makes after the error.

It seems more likely that your server has committed the transaction and the network has failed before it can return the result.

A network connection failure can happen at essentially three points;

- The connection directly at the client device can fail (ie the mobile service or wifi network is lost)
- The connection can fail directly at the server (eg the network switch to which the server is connected loses power) - this is highly unlikely in modern, fault tolerant virtualised data centres.
- The connection can fail at some other point between the client and the server.

We now need to consider what each endpoint "sees" in each of these three cases and to understand that TCP connections are quite resilient and will take quite some time to report a connection failure due to packet loss.

In the first case the client network stack sees that the network connection is physically lost and can quickly report errors on all network connections (this what you see in your app). On the server side, however, the TCP retry process means that it will be some time until the connection is seen as lost (the client device can't send a TCP packet closing the connection because it has no network connection...)

In the second instance the situation would be reversed; the server would know straight away that the network had failed (but can't tell the client) while the client would eventually get a timeout.

In the third case, both ends would experience an eventual timeout.

The first scenario is the most likely due to the nature of mobile networks (and indeed you state that it is the client that has lost the connection).

When the client connects, the server starts the transaction and presumably completes it in a short period of time, possibly a fraction of a second or a few seconds, but certainly less time than it takes for the server to receive a TCP timeout from the failed client connection.

You are now left with the situation described by Rob in his comments.  The server has completed the work but the client has received a network failure message before receiving the server reply.

You can fix this on the server. For example, it can delay committing the transaction until the response is successfully delivered to the client. If the server receives a network error sending the response to the client, it can roll back the transaction. Of course there is still the possibility of a server failure before the transaction is committed but after the response has been delivered (but this is typically unlikely); truly idempotent processing is complicated.

Alternatively you could implement a process for the client to check the state of the server after a network error to determine if the transaction completed or must be retried.

Answer (score -1):

In order to prevent URLSession from automatically retrying requests, you can set the urlCache property of your URLSessionConfiguration to nil. By default, URLSession uses an internal caching mechanism, and if a request fails, it might attempt to use a cached response when connectivity is restored.

Here's how you can modify your URLSession configuration to disable caching:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.waitsForConnectivity = true
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 1

// Disable caching
config.urlCache = nil
config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

session.dataTask(with: request.urlRequest!) { data, response, error in
     if let error = error as NSError?,
               error.code == NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost {
        session.invalidateAndCancel()
      }
}.resume()
```